# Finding maximum from column of table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find maximum value column in given table in MySql.

Table has following entry :

```
A  |  B |  C |  D
10 | 50 | 60 | 20|
```

Where A,B,C,D are column names and 10,50,60,20 are data points.

Expected output : C

Comment: is that you looking for column name or a column value?

Comment: @almasshaikh Yeah. I am expecting to get column name as output

Answer (score 0):

```
select greatest(a,b,c,d)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition in select query.I will show the example for 3 columns in a table.

if condition syntax is as follows

> if(condition,return value if true,return value if false)

This is the query

```
select if(col1>col2,if(col1>col3,col1,col3),if(col2>col3,col2,col3)) from your_table;
```